# HTML banner warning message in Google Chrome

Tags: html

I am a beginner developer and need help with this warning message. How can I disable this banner?

[image: Banner Warning Image]

Here is a piece of code:

```
        <input
          class="input-name"
          pattern="[a-zA-Zა-ჰ]+"
          type="text"
          placeholder="სახელი"
          minlength="3"
          maxlength="255"
          required
        />
```

Comment: You're imposing validation in your markup. How do you plan to convey to the user what it is?

Comment: @isherwood If the user will enter the wrong amount of symbols there will be a red error message.

Comment: See [much more on this](https://www.google.com/search?q=disable+html+validation+messages+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: If you're doing your own validation you probably shouldn't be using standard HTML validation attributes. Convert them to data attributes or something.

Comment: Also, see [ask]. You should've explained your validation strategy in your post so we know what you're trying to accomplish. It's nut such a simple question.

Comment: Can You Include more code? about do you have this `input` in `<form>`

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob I know that but 'prettier' formats it like that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I type something in input and it doesn't meet with input requirements this banner shows up right? So I wanted this banner to NOT show up when input doesn't meet requirements. I already solved it with help of @callmenikk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your `input` tag in `<form>` tags and write inside the form as attribute `novalidate` which wount show that error

*in that case make sure to hover on it, to see if it gives you warning or not*

### fixed

```html
<form novalidate>
  <input class="input-name" pattern="[a-zA-Zა-ჰ]+" type="text" placeholder="სახელი" minlength="3" maxlength="255" required />
</form>
```

### your code

```html
<input class="input-name" pattern="[a-zA-Zა-ჰ]+" type="text" placeholder="სახელი" minlength="3" maxlength="255" required />
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `required`, `minlength` and `maxlength` attributes, your input should full fill these criteria

- Because of Using `required` attribute your input should not be Empty
- Because of Using `minlength="3"` attribute, minimum number of characters in the input should be 3.
- Because of Using `maxlength="255"` attribute, your input can only hold 255 characters, nothing more than that.

Read More about HTML inputs [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp).